# How to use 32 bit compiled shared object (.so) file on 64 bit RHEL?

Tags: linux, rhel, dynamic-linking

I have a shared object file libfault.so for my 32 bit compiled application on RHEL 6.4.
I want to preload this file while starting my application. I have placed it in /usr/local/lib/ directory.

But while starting the application, i am getting the following error.

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libfault.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

But, if i compile libfault.so in 64 bit and place in /usr/local/lib64/, I do not get the error. But the file is not doing its intended function since my application is 32 bit compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the environment variable `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to override the dynamic loader's search path when looking for libraries to load.

To do it temporarily for a single application, you can invoke it like so:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib <your executable here>
```

You can make the change more permanent for your shell instance by exporting that variable:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

Adjust the paths above as needed for where ever your 32-bit `.so` is being stored.